# how work and bind with MatSelectModule in reactive form in model angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, ngx-modal

I'm working on updating receiver . When the user presses the edit button, a modal will open for him . this modal contains reactive form . i hava  problm with selector
HTML Code

```
    <div class="form-group col">
              <label>Groupes</label>
              <mat-select formControlName="groups" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="reciverToEdit.groups" 
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedE && fE.groups.errors }"  multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group">{{group.groupName}}</mat-option>
             
                </mat-select>
              
            </div>
```

TS Code :

```
editForm!:FormGroup;
  groups!:SmGroup[];
  reciverToEdit!:Receiver;
ngOnInit() {
     this.initForms(); 
}
 initForms(){
  this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     idreceiver:['', Validators.required],
     idAddress:['', Validators.required],
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      // validates date format yyyy-mm-dd
      dob: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      wilaya:[],
      commune :[],
      codepostal :['', Validators.required],
      homeNumber :[''],
      floor:[''],
      street:[''],
      city:['', Validators.required],
      groups: [],
      cat: ['', Validators.required],
      genre: ['', Validators.required]
  });
 
  // to open update model 
  openModalUpdate(template: TemplateRef<any>, reciver: Receiver) {
    this.reciverToEdit = reciver;
   this.editForm.controls['idreceiver'].setValue(this.reciverToEdit.idreceiver)
      this.editForm.controls['idAddress'].setValue(this.reciverToEdit.receiverAddress.idAddress)
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template,
      Object.assign({}, { class: 'modal-lg' })    );
      
   
  }
```

the result here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClvPN.png)

the selector not open or show any thing
i need help

Comment: You're going to need to post all the code including the typescript so we have a better idea of what you're trying to do and where it's going wrong

Comment: I edited the question, is it clear now?